# Rails js.erb not adding css.animate but no errors

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've been working through an older rails book and trying to update the code as I go. The book is for Rails 3, but I'm on 3.2 which has some differences I was hoping for help with! The project revolves around a store app and I've managed to get through most of it and get it working, except for one piece that has me pulling out my hair!

The section in question covers adding css.animate to a cart partial. The book uses js.jrs, but that isn't supported in my version of rails so I'm using a js.erb file as below:

```
$('#cart').html('<%= escape_javascript(render(@cart))%>');

$('#current_item').css({'background-color':'#88ff88'}).
animate({'background-color':'#114411'}, 1000);
```

The first piece is working fine, that's used to display and updated cart, however, I just can't seem to get the second piece working. I've been googling around and see that lots of people seem to have no issue with that code, so I'm thinking it must have something to do with my version of rails/setup. My suspicion is that the problem relates to how my line_item view is trying to access the current_item variable. But I'm not too sure on how to troubleshoot this. I've included some more of the code below for reference:

**_line_item.html.erb:**

```
<% if line_item == @current_item %>
  <tr id="current_item">
  <% else %>
    <tr>
    <% end %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= line_item.quantity %>&times;</td>
      <td><%= line_item.product.title %></td>
      <td class="item_price"><%= number_to_currency(line_item.total_price) %></td>
    </tr>
```

**line_item_contoller:**

```
def create
@cart = current_cart
product = Product.find(params[:product_id]) @line_item = @cart.add_product(product.id)
respond_to do |format| if @line_item.save
      format.html { redirect_to(store_url) }
      format.js   { @current_item = @line_item }
      format.xml  { render :xml => @line_item,
        :status => :created, :location => @line_item }
else
format.html { render :action => "new" } format.xml { render :xml => @line_item.errors,
        :status => :unprocessable_entity }
        end 
    end
end
```

I'm not too sure on how to chase down the issue so any help would be much appreciated. I've came up with a few examples where people ran through the same project, for example here: http://intertwingly.net/projects/AWDwR4/checkdepot-225-40/section-11.3.html#cmd5

I duplicated this project though and it still didn't work, that's why I believe it to primarily be a configuration difference with my version of rails.

And here is someone working through the same project successfully on github:
https://github.com/diegonetto/Learning-Ruby-on-Rails/tree/master/app/views/line_items

I know that the attr_accessible was brought in after this course, which is something I had to cater for along the way. That's what makes me lean towards an access issue.

Thanks in advance for any tips you can provide!

Comment: Is there a reason to learn an older version instead of learning Rails 5? Lot of things have changed and you will have to unlearn them when you start working with the latest version.

Comment: Hi @andHapp, yes there is a reason I must use the older version I'm afraid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the code you showed for the `_line_item.html.erb` partial, it looks like you have an extra `<tr>` opener, just below `<% end %>` so that could throw things off. Could that be part of the issue?